# MySQL, delete and index hint

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-delete, sql-execution-plan

I have to delete about 10K rows from a table that has more than 100 million rows based on some criteria. When I execute the query, it takes about 5 minutes. I ran an explain plan (the `delete` query converted to `select *` since MySQL does not support `explain delete`) and found that MySQL uses the wrong index.

My question is: is there any way to tell MySQL which index to use during delete? If not, what ca I do? Select to temp table then delete from temp table?

Comment: Ensure that you have a primary key and that the column named in the WHERE clause of your delete is indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [index hint syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html). `//ETA: sadly, not for deletes`

ETA:
Have you tried running [`ANALYZE TABLE $mytable`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html)?

If that doesn't pay off, I'm thinking you have 2 choices: Drop the offending index before the delete and recreate it after. Or JOIN your delete table to another table on the desired index which should ensure that the desired index is used.

Comment: Yes, but to my understanding index hint does not work for delete statements.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really come across a situation where MySQL chose the wrong index, but rather my understanding of how indexes worked was usually at fault.

You might want to check out this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067

It has a great section on how indexes work and other tuning options.

Comment: +1, the book opens your eyes on many things you would never think about.

Comment: Editing, dnagirl is right about index hint syntax, I didn't know that went live.

Comment: I have seen mysql choose the wrong index many times.  For us it happens on a large table (15M rows) that has a lot of similar indexes (15 indexes).  Maybe a crazy scenario --- there is a reason --- and it gets the wrong index often, even when the inde to choose should be the PRIMARY.

Comment: It's difficult to trust an answer starting from «I've never really come across a situation where MySQL chose the wrong index». This is not a rare problem. This is an everyday problem for database administrators with databases with millions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, MySQL can't use indexes, but the PRIMARY KEY index.

So your best option, if you have a PRIMARY KEY on the table is to run a fast SELECT, then DELETE according lines. Preferably in a TRANSACTION, so that you don't delete wrong rows.

Hence:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE column_with_index = 0`

Will be rewritten:

`SELECT primary_key FROM table WHERE column_with_index = 0` => returns many lines

`DELETE FROM table WHERE primary_key IN(?, ?, ?)` => `?` will be replaced by the results of the SELECTed primary keys.

If you have not that much lines to delete, it would be more efficient this way.

For example, I've just hit an exemple, on the same table, with the same data:

- 7499067 rows analyzed by DELETE : 12 seconds

vs

- 6 rows analyzed by SELECT using a good index : 0.10 seconds
- 0 rows to be deleted in the end